# Binwalk version 2.2.0 not found error when pushing to Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to push my some web development code to heroku using `git push heroku main` but I keep getting this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement binwalk==2.2.0 (from versions: 2.1.0)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for binwalk==2.2.0

Heroku is a cloud platform that lets companies build, deliver, monitor and scale apps.
Please help.

I have tried almost everything, I have uninstalled and reinstalled binwalk, I have added it as a path to .bashrc, I have moved it to /usr/local/bin but nothings works. I keep getting the same error. Whats supposed to happen is something similar to this:

> remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
> ...
> remote:
> remote: -----> Discovering process types
> remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
> remote:
> remote: -----> Compressing...
> remote:        Done: 69.2M
> remote: -----> Launching...
> remote:        Released v7
> remote:        https‍://flask-microblog.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
> remote:
> remote: Verifying deploy... done.

Heroku is a cloud platform that lets companies build, deliver, monitor and scale apps
Please help.